# Cucumber reporting service which will consumes report JSON

Tags: cucumber

I have multiple reports cucumber JSON file and maintaining HTML reports which contains (html, css and JS files) will be painful to maintain.

I'm looking for some open source service which will accept json file and returns single html file just like swagger-ui where Swagger-UI service consumes only JSON and UI will get updated as per that.

I'm new to cucumber and I tried to search it on google but didn't found anything.